# How do I include a file that is in an excluded folder in webpack?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

Here's what my code looks like for babel

```
exclude: [
  path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'node_modules'),
  path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'app','_native'),
  path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'node_modules', 'react-d3-shape', '.babelrc')
],
include: [
  path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'app'),
  path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'node_modules', 'react-d3-shape', 'lib', 'components', 'pie.js')
]
```

I want to run pie.js through babel, but it won't since its parent folder is in exclude. I tried swapping include and exclude but that didn't work. I can't for the life of me find the documentation that explains how include/exclude behave under such scenarios.

Any help would be appreciated.